# Found function in ida pro, but address keeps changing

Tags: ida

I am trying to learn reverse engeneering, so I wrote a little hackme (Very basic console application, asks for a password, and outputs 'right' or 'wrong'). The first thing I wanted to do was finding the address of the '_' function, which basically outputs the given string in the console. After some searching, I found my function, but when placing a breakpoint and debugging or restarting the application, sometimes the function address changes.

My questions:

- Why is the address changing
- How could I dynamically find the function if I can't prevent it from changing?

[image: Ida screenshot]

Comment: This is a security feature of Windows and is called [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: Try recompiling with /DYNAMICBASE:no https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx

Comment: I could compile my own application with /DYNAMICBASE:no, but what about other applications? Is there a dynamic way to find the function? Does ASLR mix everything or just the module? If it's just the module I could find the module base addr. and calculate the offset, right?

Comment: You can disable ASLR for other apps [using this](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2010/10/17/setdllcharacteristics/), or get the relative address in the form of `base + offset` and have it right every time.

Comment: you can also try debugging in an older OS that doesn't support ASLR, in case the file is self-checking and complains if you change the DLLCharacteristics field

Comment: I resolved my problem by calculating the relative offset to the module start, and when trying to find the function again, simply adding the offset to the new module base (As AcidShout suggested). Feel free to post your answer (as non-comment) so i can mark it as answer